# Getting Around Terraform's Limitations

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to setup terraform to handle creation of fine-grained user permissions, and have been able to create:

1. Cognito User Pools, Identity Pools
2. IAM Roles, Permissions

What I'm struggling with is how to link them together.  I have two types of user:

1. Standard User
2. Manager

As such, I have found two ways that I could use to correctly hook up the correct IAM policy upon login:

- Method 1 - Create a custom attribute, and Use the "Choose Role With Rules" to set a rule to set an IAM policy based on the attribute
- Method 2 - Create Cognito Groups, and link users and the required IAM policy to each group.

The problem, as far as I can see, is that Terraform doesn't currently support either of those cases, so I need to find a work around.  So, my question is essentially, how do I get around terraform's lack of support in some areas?

I've seen some projects that use [Ruby, Go, etc.] to make up for some of the limitations, but I don't quite understand where to start and what is the best option for my needs.  I haven't been able to find much in Google yet (possibly https://github.com/infrablocks/ruby_terraform).  Does anyone have a good guide or resource I could use to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If terraform does not support something you can use the `local-exec` provisioner to execute commands after resource creation. For example you could use the aws cli to add a custom attribute:

```
resource "aws_cognito_identity_pool" "main" {
  # ...    
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws cognito-idp add-custom-attributes --user-pool-id ${aws_cognito_identity_pool.main.id} --custom-attributes <your attributes>"
  }
}
```

[local-exec docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html)